# prime31. SocialNetwork iOs. Check system account is present

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine, prime31, local-system-account

I use SocialNetworkPlugin for iOs by Prime31 ([here](https://prime31.com/docs#iosSocial))
I want to use login to Fb with SystemAccount if present, but when I haven't it on device - I can't login and take Exception code 308.
I have other login logic but I need use it only when I haven't system account.
Can I check system account for Facebook before first login?

upd:
If you can write in c# please.

Comment: in which platform you are developing your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To detect about the system account for the Facebook in ios you can use :

```
if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) 
{

//user is already logged in using iOS integrated FB a/c

}
else
{

//user is not logged in

}
```

And ss per your given link for SocialNetworkPlugin Prime[31] you can use :

```
// Checks to see if the user is using a version of iOS that supports the Facebook composer and if they have an account setup 

public static bool canUserUseFacebookComposer()
```

Comment: can you write this on c#?

Comment: does not work. i've removed my facebook account, it still returns true.